# XSLT: need alternative to document()-function for multi-source processing

Tags: xslt

I'm adapting an XSLT from a third party which transforms an arbitrary number of XMLs into a single HTML document. It's a pretty complex script and it will be revised in the future, so I'm trying to do a minimal adaptation in order to get it to work for our needs.

The following is a stripped down version of the XSLT (containing the essentials):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 
    <xsl:param name="files" select="document('files.xml')//File"/>
    <xsl:param name="root" select="document($files)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$root/RootNode">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="RootNode">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Node">
            <xsl:text>Node: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now `files.xml` contains a list of all the URLs of the files to be included (in this case the local files `file1.xml` and `file2.xml`). Because we want to read XMLs from memory rather than from disk, and because the invocation of the XSLT only allows for a single XML source, I have combined the two files in a single XML document. The following is a combination of two files (there may be more in a real situation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TempNode>
    <RootNode>
        <Node>1</Node>
        <Node>2</Node>
    </RootNode> 
    <RootNode>
        <Node>3</Node>
        <Node>4</Node>  
    </RootNode>
</TempNode>
```

where the first `RootNode` originally resided in `file1.xml` and the second in `file2.xml`.
Due to the complexity of the actual XSLT, I've figured that my best shot is to try to alter the `$root`-param. I've tried the following:

```
<xsl:param name="root" select="/TempNode"/>
```

The problem is this. In the case of `<xsl:param name="root" select="document($files)"/>`, the XPath expression `"//Node"` in `<xsl:for-each select="//Node">` selects the Node's from `file1.xml` and `file2.xml` independently, i.e. producing the following (desired) list:

Node: 1, Node: 2, Node: 3, Node: 4,

However, when I combine the content of the two files into a single XML and parse this (and use the suggested `$root`-definition), the expression `"//Node"` will select all Node's that are children of the `TempNode`. (In other words, the desired list, as represented above, is produced twice due to the combination with the outer `<xsl:for-each select="$root/RootNode">` loop.)

(A side note: as observed in comment a) in [this page](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2602.html#d3862e214), `document()` apparently changes the root node, perhaps explaining this behavior.)

My question becomes: 
**How can I re-define `$root`, using the combined XML as source instead of a multi-source through document(), so that the list is only produced once, without touching the remainder of the XSLT?** It's like if `$root` defined using the `document()`-function, there is no common root node in the param. Is it possible to define a param with two "separate" node trees?

Btw: I've tried defining a document like this

```
<xsl:param name="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="/TempNode/*">
        <xsl:document>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:param>
```

thinking it might solve the problem, but the `"//Node"` expression still fetches all the Nodes. Is the context node in the `<xsl:template match="RootNode">`-template actually somewhere in the input document and not the param? (Honestly, I'm pretty confused when it comes to context nodes.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 good question, and obviously a good amount of care went into explaining and formatting the description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks LarsH! In my opinion, you won't get a good answer unless the question is posed correctly. I hope it wasn't too bloated, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Updated more)**

OK, some of the problem is becoming clear. First, just to make sure I understand, you aren't actually passing parameters for `$files` and `$root` to the XSLT processor invocation, right? (They might as well be variables rather than params?)

Now to the main issues... In XPath, when you evaluate an expression that begins with "/" (including "//"), the context node is ignored **[mostly]**. Therefore, when you have

```
<xsl:template match="RootNode">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Node">
```

the matched RootNode is ignored. Maybe you wanted

```
<xsl:template match="RootNode">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//Node">
```

in which the for-each would select Node elements that are descendants of the matched RootNode? **This would fix your problem of generating the desired node list twice.**

I inserted **[mostly]** above because I recalled that an "absolute location path" starts from "the root node of the document containing the context node". So the context node does affect what document is used for "//Node". Maybe that's what you intended all along? I guess I was slow to catch on to that.

> (A side note: as observed in comment
>   a) in this page, document() apparently
>   changes the root node, perhaps
>   explaining this behavior.)

Or [more precisely](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths),

> An absolute location path ["/..."]
>   followed by a relative location
>   path... selects the set of nodes that
>   would be selected by the relative
>   location path relative to the root
>   node **of the document containing the
>   context node**.

`document()` doesn't actually change anything, in the sense of side effects; rather, it returns a set of nodes contained (usually) by different documents than the primary source document. XSLT instructions like `xsl:apply-templates` and `xsl:for-each` establish new values for the context node inside the scope of their template bodies. So if you use `xsl:apply-templates` and `xsl:for-each` with select="document(...)/...", the context node inside the scope of those instructions will belong to an external document, so any use of "/..." as an XPath will start from that external document.

**Updated again**

> How can I re-define $root, using the
>   combined XML as source instead of a
>   multi-source through document(), so
>   that the list is only produced once,
>   without touching the remainder of the
>   XSLT?

As @Alej hinted, it's really not possible given the above constraint. If you're selecting "//Node" in each iteration of the loop over "$root/RootNode", then in order for each iteration *not* to select the same nodes as the other iterations, each value of "$root/RootNode" must be in a different document. Since you're using the combined XML source, instead of a multi-source, this is not possible.

But if you don't insist that your `<xsl:for-each select="//...">` XPath expression cannot change, it becomes very easy. :-) Just put a "." before the "//".

> It's like if $root defined using the document()-function, there is no common root node
>   in the param.

The value of the param is a node-set. All nodes in the set may be contained in the same document, or they may not, depending on whether the first argument to document() is a nodeset or just a single node.

> Is it possible to define a param with two "separate" node trees?

I believe by "separate", you mean "belonging to different documents"? Yes it is, but I don't think you can do it in XSLT 1.0 unless you're selecting nodes that belong to different documents in the first place.

You mentioned trying

```
<xsl:param name="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="/TempNode/*">
        <xsl:document>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:param>
```

but `<xsl:document>` is not defined in XSLT 1.0, and your stylesheet says version="1.0". Do you have XSLT 2.0 available? If so, let us know and we can pursue this option. To be honest, `<xsl:document>` is not familiar territory for me. But I'm happy to learn along with you.

Comment: @LarsH: You are right about the problem. This is because the use of an absolute path `//Node` (`/descendant-or-self::node()/child::Node` where first **/** means the document root). The list is produced twice because there is two `RootNode` in the mixed input.

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't understand how this could be. What mixed input? For the expression "//Node" there is only one "/", i.e. the root node of the document of the context node. That document, as I understand, is the combined XML document which has a top-level TempNode element, with two RootNode children, and four Node grandchildren. Each `Node` should be selected exactly once by the expression "//Node". I guess I'm still missing something.

Comment: @LarsH: In OP' stylysheet there is a rule matching `RootNode`. This process **all** descendant `Node` with the expression `//Node`. But in Op's mixed input source there is **two** `RootNode` elements.

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks for your reply! I can see why my post was a little misleading, so I've edited it slightly to improve readability. Hope it gets clearer now. What Alejandro is referring to as mixed input is my combination of two XML files, file1.xml and file2.xml. (Basically copy & paste. In the real world, the mixed input will be produced in memory by an application.) So the list that should read "Node: 1, Node: 2, Node: 3, Node: 4,", actually reads "Node: 1, Node: 2, Node: 3, Node: 4, Node: 1, Node: 2, Node: 3, Node: 4," (but I guess you got that). +1 for the effort!

Comment: @Alej, @conc: ooookay, nooow I get it. :-) I thought you were saying that `//Node` by itself would produce the desired list twice. But you were saying that `//Node` in combination with `<xsl:for-each select="$root/RootNode">` was producing the list twice. OK, now I'm right-side-up, let me think about it a bit.

Comment: @conciliator: Do note that this is because your transformation have more than necesary rules. Just one rule matching `Node` should be enough (And maybe an empty rule matching text nodes).

Comment: @LarsH: yup, that's the one. :) I'll see if I can improve the question to prevent others from being mislead. (And I sure am looking forward to any solution you might have!) @Alejandro: I'm intrigued by your comment. I've pretty much used call-template so far 'cause I feel more at home with them, so I don't really get what you're aiming at. (In other words; I haven't used apply-templates in conjunction with match so much.) Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @conciliator: Of course. Try this stylesheet: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/><xsl:template match="text()"/><xsl:template match="Node"><xsl:value-of select="concat('Node: ',.,substring(', ',1 div boolean(following::Node)))"/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: @Alej, you're being very gentlemanly in not posting an answer, apparently not wanting to take rep points where I already spent time. But posting a stylesheet in a comment is going a little overboard. :-) Go ahead and post an answer so that the OP can get the full benefit of your ideas.

Comment: @LarsH: From OP's comments in other answer: *I'd like to stress that extensive changes to the XSLT is a deal breaker for me*. Plus, questions is defined as (from edited question) **How can I re-define $root, using the combined XML as source instead of a multi-source through document(), so that the list is only produced once, without touching the remainder of the XSLT?**

Comment: @conc, I updated my answer some more. Are you actually using XSLT 2.0 instead of 1.0?

Comment: @LarsH: +1 Because this answer address all the issues as well as recomendations.

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks for the input! Now I see what you had in mind. :)

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks a lot for the extensive answer! (I wasn't aware that <xsl:document> was a 2.0 specific instruction. I believe I'm stuck with 1.0, so that's definitely an assumption. Should've been clearer on that from the get go, I guess.) Anyway, I've solved the problem in earlier versions of this XSLT using what you suggested: ".//Node" instead of "//". I'm marking your answer as accepted, due to "Since you're using the combined XML source, instead of a multi-source, this is not possible.". Thanks again!

Comment: @LarsH: Just out of curiosity: you say that "Yes it is [possible to create node sets belonging to different documents], but I don't think you can do it in XSLT 1.0 unless you're selecting nodes that belong to different documents in the first place.". Do you know how to do this in 2.0? :)

Comment: @conc: Yes, I have not tested it, but `<xsl:document>` should be able to do it in XSLT 2.0. In fact it according to Michael Kay's book, it is the *only* way to create a sequence with nodes belonging to several documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply only nodes you need:

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TempNode>
    <RootNode>
        <Node>1</Node>
        <Node>2</Node>
    </RootNode> 
    <RootNode>
        <Node>3</Node>
        <Node>4</Node>  
    </RootNode>
</TempNode>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TempNode/RootNode"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RootNode">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('RootNode-', generate-id(.), '&#10;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Node"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Node', ., '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
RootNode-N65540
Node1
Node2
RootNode-N65549
Node3
Node4
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I'd like to stress that extensive changes to the XSLT is a deal breaker for me. Thus your solution won't really cut it for my need, but I'm sure it gets the job done! ;)